# creating a button to update string parameter for RSS reader using Actionscript 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I want to create a few buttons which users can choose from to change the XML file for my RSS Reader in Air for Android.  This is what the button will need to update:

```
var rssURL: URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://newsrss.bbc.co.uk/rss/newsonline_world_edition/front_page/rss.xml");
```

The above XML is the default one I have chosen.  What code would I need for them to do this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So this sounds easy...You want to create a button that passes a new value into your URL Request() correct? Sounds like you are new. You could do something easier.

1. Create your buttons
2. Actionscript your buttons to event handlers for on Mouse Click.
3. Create a function for each of the buttons

In the function create a new URL Request. For example:

Button1 goes to function button1click inside that function you will have your RSS URL reader code.
var rssURL: URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://newsrss.bbc.co.uk/rss/newsonline_world_edition/front_page/rss.xml");

Button2 goes to function button2click inside that function you will have another RSS URL reader code.
var rssURL: URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://www.secondRSSFeed.com/XML.xml");

I don't know the real code off the top of my head, but here is what it would look like **pseudo code**.

> button1.EventListener.Click(button1Click)
>
> function button1Click { Rss reader code }

Comment: Hi thanks for replying.  I have tried your suggestion but its not updating the RSS Reader:  
sport_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, addSport);

function addSport (evt:MouseEvent)
{
 var rssURL: URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://newsrss.bbc.co.uk/rss/sportonline_uk_edition/front_page/rss.xml");
}

Comment: Not sure if this matters or not, but you could try...
sport_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,addSport); function addSport(e:MouseEvent){trace("Mouse Click Detected");} The trace will help to determine rather the mouse click is being registered. Good luck